# jQuery plugins and dynamically generated form

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use two jQuery plugins on new project of mine:

```
$("input[type=text].color").miniColors();
$("input[type=file], input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], select").uniform();
```

In this project, I have multiple upload forms that are build dynamically with jQuery - I have a hidden container `<div>` with multiple form elements in it. Depending on the user choice needed elements are being added to the form with `html()` function.

User can switch between multiple types of form with tabs (Twitter Bootstrap).

I noticed that plugins are not working correctly on those form elements.

Is there any possibility to bind function to a form with `live()` function or is there any other way?

** Edit ** 
Form is being built with following function:

```
function buildForm(target)
{
    var form = $("#" + target);

    switch(target){
        case 'image':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-src").html());
            break;
        case 'generate':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-src").html() + $("#wrapper-generate").html());
            break;
        case 'video':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-url").html());
            break;
        case 'text':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-body").html());
            break;
    }
}
```

All elements are placed outside of the form and are moved between `<form>` tags while user changes the type of the form.

What does not work? For example, in Uniform plugin, the state of the radio/select buttons are not changed (graphic is not being changed).

Cheers!

Comment: Need a little more info, and some code would nice, about what you expect to happen that isn't happening.

Comment: event delegation doesn't work unless there is an event involved. Instead, initialize those plugins as you generate the elements.

Comment: @Kevin B - I'm calling buidlForm() function twice - on page load (if there's a form with errors) and after every change of `type` input. What would you suggest to fix my issue?

Comment: initialize the plugins inside of the buildForm method, after the switch/case statement, only targeting the newly added form.

Comment: have you tried using `.clone(true)` to make a copy of the element with events rather than copying the html of the element?  You'll likely need to use `append`, `appendTo`, `insertBefore` or `insertAfter` to get it where you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the plugins inside of the `buildForm` method after the switch/case statement only targeting the newly added form.

```
function buildForm(target)
{
    var form = $("#" + target);

    switch(target){
        case 'image':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-src").html());
            break;
        case 'generate':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-src").html() + $("#wrapper-generate").html());
            break;
        case 'video':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-url").html());
            break;
        case 'text':
            form.html($("#wrapper-title").html() + $("#wrapper-body").html());
            break;
    }
    $("input[type=text].color", form).miniColors();
    $("input[type=file], input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], select", form).uniform();
}
```

Comment: the main issue is that I call buildForm() function twice. The plugins are initialized twice (ex. Uniform radio inputs graphics are loaded twice...). Any thoughts?

Comment: they shouldn't be initialized twice, buildForm completely empties the form and puts new content in it. That new content is not inialized, however it may have markup from previously initialized plugins. If that is the case, your method of building the form is flawed.

Comment: I tried also to create an empty div and put the issue still occurs. BTW. what approach of building such kind of form would you recommend?

Comment: Since you are building each form from a string of html, store a copy of that string in a variable rather than fetching it from the DOM